# Displaying frequent terms and its corresponding rows

Tags: r, text-mining

We have a document with all medical trial data details. This has been cleaned, the usual converting to Corpus, stripping whitespace, removing punctuations, transforming to lower, removing stopwords and converted to term document matrix with tri-grams, bi-grams or uni-grams. Now the frequently used terms is in an output file. I would love to show the frequently used terms in top pane and as users navigate from one frequently used word to another, I want to show the set of rows, that the term occurs in the bottom pane (The panes can be sidewise as well)

Comment: It isn't obvious what "panes" means here. Do you mean `shiny`, script files in RStudio, or something else? What have you tried so far? Do you have sample data you can provide? (If proprietary, consider a publicly-available dataset for an example.)

Comment: Some front end UI, that shows frequently occurring terms in top view of the screen with a scroller and all rows where the term occurs in bottom view of the screen. I am learning R and have been able to get the frequently used term so far

Comment: Let me make up some sample data.

Comment: What you're asking for is a suggestion for a library or package, a type of question specifically [marked as "off-topic" on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Other than a quick suggestion to take a look at [`shiny`](http://shiny.rstudio.com/), I suggest you do some research on working examples of it, play around with it, and come back with questions about code that doesn't work. If you want more advice, you might want to go to [Software Recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), another StackExchange site.

Comment: Will do. Will try shiny